# Qaudioinput has a runtime error in android

Tags: android, qt, qaudioinput

[image]I have developed an application to record voice with Qt. it works correctly in a Linux environment but it gives me a run-time error in Android when I start recording.
I have debugged my code and I think it is because of `QAudioInput` library.
I attached my error image.[image]

```
QBuffer m_buffer;
m_buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);


void Recorder::toggleRecord(QString state)
{
    if(state == "1")
    {
        m_buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);
        m_audioInput->start(&m_buffer);
        QAudioDeviceInfo info = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();
        if (!info.isFormatSupported(m_format)) {
            qWarning() << "Default format not supported, trying to use the nearest.";
            m_format = info.nearestFormat(m_format);
        }
    }
    if(state == "0")
    {
        m_buffer.close();
        m_audioInput->stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I modified my question.

Comment: how do you initialize ```m_buffer```

Comment: I modified my question.

Comment: what is the Android version and are you sure that you have RECORD_AUDIO access permission ?

Comment: Android version is 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need run-time access request for this Android version (8).

```
  auto  result = QtAndroid::checkPermission(QString("android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"));
    if(result == QtAndroid::PermissionResult::Denied){
        QtAndroid::PermissionResultMap resultHash = QtAndroid::requestPermissionsSync(QStringList({"android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"}));
        if(resultHash["android.permission.CAMERA"] == QtAndroid::PermissionResult::Denied)
            // do whatever needed if denied
         else
            // do whatever needed if granted
    }
```

You can launch it whenever your application starts.

Comment: It worked before, but now suddenly it does not work. My be it is because android version. What is your opinion?

Comment: Do you mean that this solution did not solve the problem?

Comment: #if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
#include <QtAndroid>
#endif
android {
    QT += androidextras
}
but I have error: 'checkPermission' is not a member of 'QtAndroid'
     auto  result = QtAndroid::checkPermission(QString("android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"));
                    ^

Comment: what version of Qt are you building your project against ?

Comment: my QT version is Qt5.9.4

Comment: ```QtAndroid::checkPermission``` This function was introduced in Qt 5.10. So, you should do this in a java class and call it through JNI.

Comment: in app permission it has record and storage permission

Comment: Android 8.0 needs runtime permissions.  including it in the manifest will not suffice

Comment: Android 8.0 needs runtime permissions.  including it in the manifest will not suffice